# Pyspark: PicklingError: Could not serialize object: while inserting data into dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to insert 2million items into dynamoDB (WCU = 40,000). But while I use spark map, it is throwing error.

```
%livy.pyspark
import shutil
from typing import Text, List
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
import boto3
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key


dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
table = dynamodb.Table("<dynamboDB>")
df=spark.read.parquet("s3 path").limit(10)

df.rdd.map(lambda row:  table.put_item(Item=row.asDict()))
```

**Error**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 205, in __repr__
    return self._jrdd.toString()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2532, in _jrdd
    self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2434, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2420, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 607, in dumps
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle SSLContext objects```
````

Comment: try using `foreach` instead of `map`?

Comment: what error is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

```
def copy_to_dynmodb_multiprocess(spark: SparkSession, dynamo_table_name: Text, s3_path: Text,
                                 region_name: Text = "us-east-1", **kwargs):

    compress_fields = kwargs.get("compress_fields", [])
    retention_time = kwargs.get("retention_time", None)
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region_name)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    table = dynamodb.Table(dynamo_table_name)
    parse_obj = urlparse(s3_path, allow_fragments=False)
    bucket = str(parse_obj.netloc)
    prefix = str(parse_obj.path[1:])
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    cpu_count = mp.cpu_count() - 2
    process_count = kwargs.get("process_count", cpu_count)
    s3_list = []
    for obj in response['Contents']:
        file_prefix = str(obj['Key'])
        if file_prefix.endswith(".parquet"):
            s3_list.append({"s3key": "s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, file_prefix)})

    def insert_into_dynamodb(s3list):
        key = s3list['s3key']
        data = spark.read.parquet(key)
        for row in data.rdd.collect():
            row_dict = row.asDict()
            if retention_time is not None:
                days = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_time)
                expiry_date_time = int(time.mktime(days.timetuple()))
                row_dict['expry_dt'] = expiry_date_time
            else:
                pass
            if len(compress_fields) > 0:
                for field in compress_fields:
                    row_dict[field] = gzip.compress(bytes(row_dict[field], "utf-8"))
                table.put_item(Item=row_dict)
            else:
                table.put_item(Item=row_dict)
    p = Pool(processes=process_count)
    p.map(insert_into_dynamodb, s3_list)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).